# Dynamic orderBy in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects I want to order dynamically, based on a value from a drop down menu. This is what I have so far in my list:

```
ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (items | filter:searchInput | orderBy:canBeAnything)"
```

But the problem however is that the sorting can be an attribute of the object or a calculated value using a function. It also should be able to sort in a descending way (optionally).

I know I can use a string for the canByAnything variable behind the orderBy passing an attribute of the object like:

```
“-creationDate” // descending ordering on creation date
“customer.lastname” // ascending ordering on customers last name
```

I also know I can orderBy a function like:

```
orderBy:myCalculatedValueFunction // will order in an ascending way based on a calculated value, for example calculating the total price of the object if it was an order or something
```

But what I don't know and want to achieve is:

- How to combine it so I can use function(s) for sorting in combination with attributes/properties of the objects. I mean one or the other, dynamically, based on what the user has selected. Which can be an attribute or a calculated value, either descending or ascending.
- How to sort a calculated value in a descending way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update `orderBy:myCalculatedValueFunction` to something like `orderBy:dynamicOrderFunction`:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> $scope.dynamicOrderFunction = function() {
>     if (orderByString) {
>         return '-creationDate';
>     }
>     else {
>         return myCalculatedValueFunction;
>     }
> }
> ```

`orderBy` also has a 3rd property that accepts a boolean and will reverse orderBy when `true`. (`orderBy:dynamicOrderFunction:reverseOrder` where `$scope.reverseOrder = true; // or false`)

---

**edit**

You will actually run into issues trying to switch orderBy between a string a function this way. Checkout out [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csbarnes/2gb2azok) for a working dynamic order function.

```
$scope.dynamicOrder = function(user) {
    var order = 0;
    switch ($scope.order.field) {
        case 'gender':
            order = gender_order[user.gender];
            break;
        default:
            order = user[$scope.order.field];
    }
    return order;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have to create your own filter and do what ever you want in it,
there's tons of example on google. Just search :

**angular custom filter**

Theses last days, i experience somes issues with filters creation and i found that:
https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

I've added it immediately in my dependcies, i know i will use it really soon. May be it will help you too.
 Don't forget to valid my answer if it helps you to resolve your problem ;)