# ng-repeat with title and also sorting array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

We have a JSON object and we do have a different requirement to display in a different form.

The object:

```
[
    {name: a1, marks:10},
    {name: b3, marks:10},
    {name: b2, marks:10},
    {name: c1, marks:10},
    {name: b1, marks:10},
    {name: a2, marks:10}
]
```

To display UI:

On click of sort by name

```
A: name: a1, name: a2, name: a3
B: name: b1, name: b2, name: b3
C: name: c1, name: c2, name: c3
```

And onclik of sort by marks (not to sort by name inside marks)

```
10: name: a2, name: c1, name: a3
11: name: a1, name: b2, name: b3
12: name: c1, name: a2, name: c3
```

Can anyone help please?

Have tried:

```
<div ng-repeat="letter in ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']">
  <div class="folders_only col-xs-12"  ng-show="getFilesOfType(letter).length">
    <div>
      <span>{{letter}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat='val in getFilesOfType(letter)'></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

But problem is I have json object which gets more data on scrolling down each time, so new data doesnt reflect in UI

Comment: What did you try, until now?

Comment: Just see this http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/AmFLE example and try it on your own.

Comment: What i understand from your question is you need dynamic sort based on some variable. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635796/dynamic-orderby-in-angularjs

Comment: @Luckyy Your question is not clear. You want to sort an array. Again you are saying `I have json object which gets more data on scrolling down each time, so new data doesnt reflect in UI`. What do you mean by `new data doesnt reflect in UI` ? And, What does your `getFilesOfType(letter)` return? It will be better if you can create fiddle/plunker.