# AngularJS - Sorting data ascending / descending when column is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have the following view code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in clients | orderBy:'code'">
    <td>{{c.firstname}} {{c.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{c.telephone}}</td>
    <td>{{c.location}}</td>
    <td>{{c.code}}</td>
</tr>
```

I want to change the `orderBy:'code'` when column is clicked, assume that the user clicked on the column location, i want the `orderBy` condition to change to 'location' instead of code, and to be in this form

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in clients | orderBy:'location'">
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic orderBy in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635796/dynamic-orderby-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.prefix = '+';
  $scope.sort = '';
  $scope.sortFn = function(name) {
    $scope.prefix = $scope.prefix == '-' ? '+' : '-';
    $scope.sort = $scope.prefix + name;
  }
  $scope.arrow = function(name){
    if($scope.sort.indexOf(name) != -1)
      return $scope.prefix == '+' ? '↑' : '↓';
    return '';
  }

  $scope.clients = [
    { name: 'Tom', age: 30 },
    { name: 'Max', age: 20 },
    { name: 'Sam', age: 40 },
    { name: 'Liza', age: 25 },
    { name: 'Henry', age: 35 }
  ]
})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th{
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<table ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <thead>
    <tr>      
      <th ng-click='sortFn("name")'>Name {{arrow("name")}}</th>
      <th ng-click='sortFn("age")'>Age {{arrow("age")}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in clients | orderBy:sort">
      <td>{{c.name}}</td>
      <td>{{c.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use datatables.js for automate sorting
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Answer (score 0):

write ng-click on the column and call a function like setSortByParameter and set the field sortBy.

and now write the orderBy as below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in clients | orderBy:'{{sortBy}}'">
```