# AngularJS dynamic sort function with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

Based on [Dynamic orderBy in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635796/dynamic-orderby-in-angularjs) I try to implement a dynamic sort function with parameters. It's not working properly because the default sort is being called. How can I make it not calling the default sort by name?

I have 2 buttons to call the function and send the parameter.

```
<button ng-click="dynamicOrder('f9.id')" class="btn">Sort by rating</button>            
<button ng-click="dynamicOrder('name')" class="btn">Sort alphabetic</button>
```

My ng-repeat looks like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in cumulus.items | orderBy: dynamicOrder()"
    ng-show="cumulus.items.length > 0" class="block-grid-item">
    <p>
        <a target="_blank" href="{{ item.image }}">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ item.thumb }}">
        </a>
    </p>
    <p style="overflow: hidden;">{{ item.name }}</p>                    
    <p class="text-primary"><input type="hidden" value="{{ item.f9.id }}" /> {{ item.f9.displaystring }}</p>
</li>
```

and my function for order

```
$scope.dynamicOrder = function (sortParam) {
    if (!sortParam) {            
        return 'name';
    } else {
        console.log("sortParam: ", typeof (sortParam), sortParam);
        return sortParam;
    }  
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `orderBy` expression can be a getter function. This function will be called with each item as argument and the return value will be used for sorting.

```
$scope.getterFn = function(item) {
    if ($scope.dynamicOrder == 'f9.id') {
        return item.f9.id;
    } else if ($scope.dynamicOrder == 'name') {
        return item.name;
    } else {
        return item;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
<button ng-click="dynamicOrder = 'f9.id'" class="btn">Sort by rating</button>
<button ng-click="dynamicOrder = 'name'" class="btn">Sort alphabetic</button>

<li ng-repeat="item in cumulus.items | orderBy: getterFn">

    <!-- ... -->

</li>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `orderBy` Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#usage)